# Putting google analyitics on xml specific item

Tags: xml, xslt, google-analytics

> I need to put google analytic on specific item in xml file.

```
<xsl:attribue rel="onClick">
 <h3 onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','<xsl:value-of select="Title"/>','Accordion']);">
               <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
           </h3>
</xsl:attribue>
```

> I think it goes something like this but i've got some error, so if anybody knows how to work this,please help..
>   Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want ant *attribute value template* (note the braces).

```
<h3 onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','{Title}','Accordion']);">
  <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
</h3>
```

---

I have no idea what you want with `<xsl:attribue rel="onClick">` I don't know, though. That's completely wrong.

Comment: Cause i have lots of accordions, and every has its own title, i want on every click to show title of that specific accordion.

Comment: I understand what the code should do, but `<xsl:attribue rel="onClick">` is still completely wrong. It's not valid XSLT code (`rel` is not defined in XSLT), and even if it was it could never have `<h3>` as a child.

Comment: but can I do this, i think i made an error:
<xsl:attribue name="onClick">
                    <h3 onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','<xsl:value-of select="Title"/>','Accordion']);">
                   <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
               </h3>
                </xsl:attribue>

Comment: instead of rel i will put name ?

Comment: Maybe you should include the HTML you want to get out of this. Edit your question accordingly.

Comment: what do you mean? And do you know solution for this ? :)